# Android - How to use recycler view inside recycler view

Tags: android

how can i create this type of view in android there row and column ,both sides data will be coming from api. what component of android studio , i have to use it ?
can anyone please help me , i have to color also the fix row and column.

i tried with recycler view inside recycler view but its didn't working.

```
                      <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:orientation="horizontal" />
```

[image: Image is here...]

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [GridLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout). 
It have rows and columns and may be that you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use GridLayoutManager

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(context, columnCount));
```

If you want 4 columns, replace columnCount with 4.